# Compiling OmniORB4 with Clang++

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++, omniorb

I'm learning Corba with OmniORB and try to compile simple example program but it doesn't work. Unfortunately is really hard to find some information how to do it.

What I do looks like:

1. I made simple interface file in `idl` directory

   ```
   interface IssueAlert {
     string sendAlert(in string alert);
   };
   ```
2. Compile it using `omniidl -bcxx -Wbexamples echo.idl`
3. I get result files and using examples made that code as a server app.

   ```
   #include "idl/echo.hh"
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;


   class IssueAlert_i : public POA_IssueAlert {
     public:
       IssueAlert_i();
       virtual ~IssueAlert_i();
       char* sendAlert(const char* alert);
   };

   IssueAlert_i::IssueAlert_i(){}
   IssueAlert_i::~IssueAlert_i(){}

   char* IssueAlert_i::sendAlert(const char* alert){
     cout << "Upcall: " << alert << endl;
     return CORBA::string_dup(alert);
   }

   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   int main(int argc, char** argv){
      try {
        CORBA::ORB_var          orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv);
        CORBA::Object_var       obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");
        PortableServer::POA_var poa = PortableServer::POA::_narrow(obj);

        PortableServer::Servant_var<IssueAlert_i> issue = new 
        IssueAlert_i();

        PortableServer::ObjectId_var issue_id = poa->activate_object(issue);

         // Obtain a reference to the object, and print it out as a
         // stringified IOR.
         obj = issue->_this();
         CORBA::String_var sior(orb->object_to_string(obj));
         cout << sior << endl;

         PortableServer::POAManager_var pman = poa->the_POAManager();
         pman->activate();

         // Block until the ORB is shut down.
         orb->run();
      }catch (CORBA::SystemException& ex) {
        cerr << "Caught CORBA::" << ex._name() << endl;
      }catch (CORBA::Exception& ex) {
        cerr << "Caught CORBA::Exception: " << ex._name() << endl;
      }
      return 0;
   }
   ```
4. To compile it i'm using command:

   ```
   clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wnarrowing -Wsign-conversion -lomniORB4 -lomnithread -lomniDynamic4 servant.cpp -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib64/ -o server
   ```

All OmniORB things installed by yum are in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib64`.
I get that error:

```
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o: In function `IssueAlert_i::IssueAlert_i()':
    servant.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::~_impl_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o: In function `IssueAlert_i::~IssueAlert_i()':
    servant.cpp:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to                 `POA_IssueAlert::~POA_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o: In function `IssueAlert_i::~IssueAlert_i()':
    servant.cpp:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::~_impl_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o: In function `POA_IssueAlert::_this()':
    servant.cpp:
    (.text._ZN14POA_IssueAlert5_thisEv[_ZN14POA_IssueAlert5_thisEv]+0x1e): undefined reference to `IssueAlert::_PD_repoId'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x68): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_dispatch(omniCallHandle&)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x70): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_ptrToInterface(char const*)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x78): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_mostDerivedRepoId()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0xf0): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_ptrToInterface(char const*)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x100): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_mostDerivedRepoId()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x120): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_dispatch(omniCallHandle&)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x288): undefined reference to `typeinfo for POA_IssueAlert'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x290): undefined reference to `POA_IssueAlert::~POA_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x298): undefined reference to `POA_IssueAlert::~POA_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x2a8): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_dispatch(omniCallHandle&)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x2b0): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_ptrToInterface(char const*)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x2b8): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_mostDerivedRepoId()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x318): undefined reference to `typeinfo for POA_IssueAlert'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x320): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to POA_IssueAlert::~POA_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x328): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to POA_IssueAlert::~POA_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x330): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_ptrToInterface(char const*)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x340): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_mostDerivedRepoId()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x360): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_dispatch(omniCallHandle&)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x3c8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for POA_IssueAlert'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x3d0): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to POA_IssueAlert::~POA_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x3d8): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to POA_IssueAlert::~POA_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x458): undefined reference to `typeinfo for _impl_IssueAlert'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x460): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::~_impl_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x468): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::~_impl_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x478): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_dispatch(omniCallHandle&)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x480): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_ptrToInterface(char const*)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x488): undefined reference to `_impl_IssueAlert::_mostDerivedRepoId()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x4e8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for _impl_IssueAlert'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x4f0): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::~_impl_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x4f8): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::~_impl_IssueAlert()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x500): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_ptrToInterface(char const*)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x510): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_mostDerivedRepoId()'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x530): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to _impl_IssueAlert::_dispatch(omniCallHandle&)'
    /tmp/servant-e9e6b6.o:(.rodata+0x6d0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for POA_IssueAlert'
    clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone help me with this compilation - unfortuantelly final project i want to do must use C++17 then best will be to stay with this compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wnarrowing -Wsign-conversion -lomniORB4 -lomnithread -lomniDynamic4 servant.cpp idl/echoSK.cc -o server
```

It just require to add `echoSK.cc` into command.